# Rails html_safe not escaping html

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a model that stores text formatted by Tinymce. The show view calls it like so

```
<%= @resource.content.html_safe %>
```

And up until now it worked fine (Although I hear it's better to store the characters already escaped in the database, how do I do that?), it suddenly stopped working and rendering html. h, raw and html_safe don't work.

Any idea what's going on? I've looked at any recent changes but nothing seems to fix it.

Comment: what does the above output look like?

Comment: @emaillenin Actually, now that I look at it, for some reason tinymce outputs bbcode. I'll look into this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
(CGI::unescapeHTML @resource.content).html_safe
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, the bbcode option was enabled in tinymce.yml and while I didn't notice, was actually outputting bbcode not html. Completely overlooked, thanks for the repies!